# docker -w dir prefixed with another dir

Tags: docker

When running a docker image I want to pass the -w command to set the working dir and then run bash to get inside the pod. On my ubuntu server this works just fine. However running in gitbash on my windows pc locally it seems to prefix the dir i want to set as the working dir.

```
docker run -it -w "/data/staging" -e VAULT_ADDR=$VAULT_ADDR -e VAULT_TOKEN=$VAULT_TOKEN -v "C:\Users\cdoyle\PycharmProjects\image-builds-devops-pipelines:/data/staging" image-builder bash
```

Docker then errors with

```
docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Users/cdoyle/AppData/Local/Fork/gitInstance/2.33.1/data/staging' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
```

When i look in my env for this fork path, the only thing i find is

```
$ env | grep -i fork
EXEPATH=C:\Users\cdoyle\AppData\Local\Fork\gitInstance\2.33.1\bin
```

Does anyone know why the path to `fork` is being prefixed to the working dir i am trying to pass to docker run

Comment: found an answer in another question so closing this one myself but without answering it and repeating the previous answer